# Ruby - rails - subtract date time

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a method in ruby/rails for adding/subtracting date and time along with timezone and the output to be as count of days, hours, minutes and seconds instead of DataTime format?

```
t1 = "2012-05-05 00:00:02 -0400"
t2 = "2012-05-04 00:00:00 -0500"

time_diff = (Time.now() - Time.parse(t1)).to_s
#Or
time_diff = (Time.parse(t1) - Time.parse(t2)).to_s
```

I am looking for `1 Day, 01:59:58`
The result should `#of Days HH:MM:SS` format

Comment: Shouldn't the result be 23 hours and 2 seconds?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - Right, I did it wrong. It's too complicated to do all this math manually. so basically the result should `#of Days HH:MM:SS`. :) Tried to do this MySql, had no luck there. Either Ruby or MySql shall do this math.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know there's nothing built-in to Ruby or Rails to do this. There is [`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words), but it gives a fuzzier time than you seem to be looking for (e.g. "about 7 days").

It's fairly trivial to write a method to do this, though. Given a difference in seconds, this will give you the days, hours, and seconds in the difference:

```
def time_length seconds
  days = (seconds / 1.day).floor
  seconds -= days.days
  hours = (seconds / 1.hour).floor
  seconds -= hours.hours
  minutes = (seconds / 1.minute).floor
  seconds -= minutes.minutes
  { days: days, hours: hours, minutes: minutes, seconds: seconds }
end

time_length(Time.parse(t1) - Time.parse(t2))
#=> {:days=>0, :hours=>23, :minutes=>0, :seconds=>2.0}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! You are always helping!